# Using mutable Before/After/Around in Specs2

Tags: scala, specs2

I am trying to run a mutable specs2 test with After and Around methods.
I have the following:

```
import org.specs2.mutable.{Specification, Around, After}
import org.specs2.specification.Scope
import org.specs2.execute.{Result, AsResult}

trait Foo extends After with Around {

  override def apply[T: AsResult](a: => T): Result = {
    lazy val result = super[Around].apply(a)
    super[After].apply(result)
  }

  override def after: Any = {
    println("after-method\n")
  }

  override def around[T: AsResult](t: => T) = {
    try {
      println("around-method\n")
      AsResult.effectively(t)
    } catch {
      case e: Throwable => {
        //preform some logic here
        throw e
      }
    }
  }
}

class Specs2Test extends Specification {
  "This test" should {
    "run with around and after" in new Context {
      true must_== true
    }
  }

  trait Context extends Scope with Foo

}
```

When I execute the test, only the around method is executed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that the `Around` trait's `delayedInit` method is overriding the same method in `After`.

Note, you could simply call your after logic after `AsResult.effectively(t)` for the required effect.

```
def around[T : AsResult](t: =>T) {
  // before logic
  val result = AsResult.effectively(t)
  // after logic
  result
}
```

Comment: Yes but I'm trying to separate concerns so I need them to work separately.